# Can a java class object be a state variable in another class?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a Car class in Java and then I make another class called ElectricCar. Can a Car object be a state variable in my ElectricCar class?

Comment: Yes it can......

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Comment: It would work, because every `ElectricCar` is a `Car`, but not every `Car` has to be an `ElectricCar`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put: yes. Try it:

```
class Car {
}

class ElectricCar {
    Car myCar = new Car();
}
```

Comment: @Tad Then ask a new question with all your info.

Comment: You could make this even simpler by leaving out the Car ctor.

Comment: if I instantiate an ElectricCar object in "main" and want to access the attributes/state variables of the Car object, how would I do this?  if my ElectricCar object name is electricOne, and let's say there is a Car state variable called engineSize that has a default value of 350. How can I get this value using the ElectricCar instance? Thanks!

Comment: @Tad you should be able to, from the main class, access this like so: electricOne.myCar.engineSize

Comment: actually just got it. needed to make my Car state variables public rather than private. But is that right?  Under my question, I would access the engineSize by calling electricOne.myCar.engineSize.  But shouldn't I be able to keep engineSize private in the Car class and still be able to access it using electricOne.myCar.engineSize?

Comment: private in java means only its parent class or inheriting classes can access it. So, engineSize would need to be public (or package-private if you are using a package)

Comment: Many thanks!  I've been working Python for too long and just got away from Java. If you don't use it you lose it!

Comment: no problem! If your question is answered fully, would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; and it's quite common:

```
class Car {
}

class ElectricCar {
    private final Car car;

    ElectricCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

}
```